# The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part

Tags: python, numpy

I am running an optimization code and getting this error.
`Structure' <class Structure>: Error calling compute(), setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (4,) + inhomogeneous part.`

The related structure class is:

```py
def structure(pf, x_str, Z, L, WE):
    t = Z[0]*Z[5]/(np.sqrt(abs(Z[5]*Z[3])))
    b = np.sqrt(abs(Z[5]*Z[3]))/2.0
    R = (1.0+2.0*x_str[0])/(3.0*(1.0+x_str[0]))
    Theta = pf([abs(x_str[1]), b, R, L],
                         [2, 4, 4, 3], [0.25]*4, "twist")

    Fo1 = pf([x_str[1]], [1], [.008], "Fo1")

    WT_hat = L
    WW = Fo1 * (0.0051 * abs(WT_hat*NZ)**0.557 * \
                abs(Z[5])**0.649 * abs(Z[3])**0.5 * abs(Z[0])**(-0.4) \
                * abs(1.0+x_str[0])**0.1 * (0.1875*abs(Z[5]))**0.1 \
                / abs(np.cos(Z[4]*np.pi/180.)))
    WFW = 5.0/18.0 * abs(Z[5]) * 2.0/3.0 * t * 42.5
    WF = WFW + WFO
    WT = WO + WW + WF + WE
    sigma = zeros(5)
    sigma[0] = pf([Z[0], L, x_str[1], b, R], [4, 1, 4, 1, 1], [0.1]*5, "sigma[1]")
    sigma[1] = pf([Z[0], L, x_str[1], b, R], [4, 1, 4, 1, 1], [0.15]*5, "sigma[2]")
    sigma[2] = pf([Z[0], L, x_str[1], b, R], [4, 1, 4, 1, 1], [0.2]*5, "sigma[3]")
    sigma[3] = pf([Z[0], L, x_str[1], b, R], [4, 1, 4, 1, 1], [0.25]*5, "sigma[4]")
    sigma[4] = pf([Z[0], L, x_str[1], b, R], [4, 1, 4, 1, 1], [0.30]*5, "sigma[5]")
    return Theta, WF, WT, sigma

class Structure(ExplicitComponent):

    def __init__(self, scalers):
        super(Structure, self).__init__()
        # scalers values
        self.scalers = scalers
        # Polynomial function initialized with given constant values
        self.pf = PolynomialFunction()

    def setup(self):
        # Global Design Variable z=(t/c,h,M,AR,Lambda,Sref)
        self.add_input('z', val=np.ones(6))
        # Local Design Variable x_str=(lambda,section caisson)
        self.add_input('x_str', val=np.ones(2))
        # Coupling parameters
        self.add_input('L', val=1.0)
        self.add_input('WE', val=1.0)
        # Coupling output
        self.add_output('WT', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Theta', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('WF', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('sigma', val=np.ones(5))
        self.declare_partials('*', '*')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        Z = inputs['z']*self.scalers['z']
        x_str = inputs['x_str']*self.scalers['x_str']
        L = inputs['L']*self.scalers['L']
        WE = inputs['WE']*self.scalers['WE']
        Theta, WF, WT, sigma = structure(self.pf, x_str, Z, L, WE)

        #Unknowns
        outputs['Theta'] = Theta/self.scalers['Theta']
        outputs['WF'] = WF/self.scalers['WF']
        outputs['WT'] = WT/self.scalers['L']
        outputs['sigma'] = np.zeros(5)
        for i in range(5):
            outputs['sigma'][i] = sigma[i]/self.scalers['sigma'][i]
```

Can you please guide how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a simplified (i.e. shorter) example that includes all the imports and code necessary to reproduce this error. Your current post does not show any functions being called, where the error occurs, or include the full error message.

Comment: Sounds like you are to make a "ragged" array.  The error message has varied with numpy version, but at the core, the problem is it can't make a nice multidimensional numeric dtype array from your mix of lists or arrays.

Comment: the message you show says the error occurs in `compute()`.  But where?  Don't make us guess.